# Unable to generate DocuSign Integrator Key

Tags: c#, integration, document, docusignapi

We're integrating DocuSign for taking initials from users. When I try to generate an Integrator Key from the DocuSign Developer Sandbox as mentioned here (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Announcements-Knowledge-Base/How-to-Get-and-Setup-Your-Integrator-Key/ta-p/4587), it reloads the page but does nothing.

Any idea whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue with DocuSign that was resolved.

http://community.docusign.com/t5/Misc-Questions/Get-Demo-Integrator-Key-Doesn-t-Return-a-Key/m-p/18167/highlight/true#M931